How to deal with high voltages after applying frequency multipliers?
Below is a frequency multiplier circuit. I intend to make out of 1MHz an 100MHz frequency by applying the circuit for testing purposes. I have seen that no matter what I use for simulating, the output is not steady after the achieved frequency. It ends up with a big wave then it is starting from beginning as expected. I have taken this issue into a green circle so you can recognize.
I want to avoid this big voltages. How can I carry out this?


Can we see your input waveform as well? Also, any reason why you are operating the device under a zero-bias condition? Is this a pre-calculated operation class?

@a360pilot The input wave is a simple sine wave with 1V 1MHz frequency. This circuit is for testing purposes.

I see the artifacts of class-C operation with very low conductance angles. Those large excursions are unavoidable. You just need a better tank quality to filter them out.

@a360pilot Can you suggest a better circuit to filter the large excursions out? That would be handy.

A simple frequency multiplier like this might be appropriate for X2 or X3, not X100. You need a high-Q resonator at 100 MHz, AND you should precede this circuit with a comb generator, to increase high-frequency energy. Even so, the high-Q resonator will be required to reject 99 MHz, 101 MHz, while passing 100 MHz.

MultipIying by 100 with a single stage as shown is imo unrealistic. Two x10 stages are feasible. Use a 10 MHz crystal filter after the first stage to get a clean spectrum for the second frequency multiplier.

Let me share my observations.
Vce = 5Vdc and -1/+1V AC pulse at a 1MHz input sine rate
from on my simulator using a 0 Ohm ideal voltage source 1MHz sine the output is caused by the 0.75V peak into Vbe which drives 0.5A into the collector for 7.5% of the 1us cycle.
There is no significant spectral content at 100 MHz input.
The collector is acting as a current pump, yet it needs an input risetime Tr=0.35/BW = 3.5 ns (approx. for half-power BW) to create some 100 MHz spectrum on Vbe to pump.
After the initial start step, the ringing response dies away from leakage R (Early Effect). This should show you that you need a step input with 100 MHz spectral content.
Since the decay time is related to the load resistance and the 1.5Vpp sine input you are injecting is only conducting the collector about 7% of the time with a sinx/x response.
There is no chance of making a 100f harmonic multiplier with this frequency unless you square up the edges with a rise time < 3.5ns and a pulse width that is not 10 ns or a harmonic of this. Due to the high current you injected from the base drive, and using 100x f rate using a brief time is sensible.
So the question now is what do you have that can create a 5ns pulse width (PW50 = 5ns)  with a rise/fall time, Tr < 3.5 ns at "any Pulse repetition rate to satisfy the Q of your future load after the tank circuit?
Comparator? One-shot pulse circuit?  Common base driver. Transistor with adequate fT?  3.6V logic (74ALVxx) one-shot such as an XOR gate with a 3ns delay on one side.  The Zout on 3.6V logic is about half of 5.5V logic, which is nominally 50 ohms +/-33% for most chips.
Also what phase noise do you expect if the trigger rate is not synchronous with the output?
74ALVC86 datasheet XOR gate 1ns skew, 2.5 ns Tp
With 100x multiplier your load will have to be 1k times 50 ohms for 10% ripple.  So it is not what you want yet. Define it 1st in terms of AM ripple, phase noise etc. then decide a better way.
I have done slightly different things 45 yrs ago trying to sync a 4MHz PLL with only 1 data pulse per kbits using a custom VCXO. Essentially a 1k multiplier. It worked.

You are trying to get a multiplication of ×100 in a single bipolar transistor stage. Typically this type of multiplier is limited to being used for around ×4 per stage, and higher order multipliers are made by cascading stages.
This might be why you are running into problems. Try simulating with a lower multiplication factor and see if that solves the problem.
You can get higher multiplication factors with other devices, a step recovery diode multiplier might get you ×20.

TY for your advice. I have just tried it out, what you have said about x4 per stage. I used 4MHz frequency for the output. Now it works like a charm. No extra excursions. The output has slightly voltage differences, but I think this has nothing with the circuit. The transistor could be responsible for these waves. TY for your reply. It is handy.
